# Pass argument to view block within a minipanel

Tags: panels, views

I am having a panel page, within the panel page there will be multiple minipanels in each row.
The mini-panels have 2 views both which displays content based on the argument passed.

Basically the all the minipanels are same. The views within are also same. Only the argument passed change. But I am not getting how to pass argument.

See the below picture for detail.

[image]

In the end we'll have something like this. A repeated series of same panels and views with different contents.

[image]

I am not able to find out whats wrong.

Comment: After reading your question, I get the impression you can't get any mini-panel, to pass any argument to any view? If so, is your question "How to pass arguments from mini-panels to views?". And if that's not your question, then I don't understand what is?

Comment: No, I have not succeeded in passing argument to any view in minipanel.

Comment: Then I must wonder why your question has so many, to that problem, unrelated details.

Comment: I added this much detail, so that I can explain why am doing it. Maybe the whole approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the exact same thing on my site, so writing it up here for future reference.

**Your views**:

- Create these as content panes
- Contextual filter = Content: thas taxonomy term id (in this case)
- Argument input (under "Pane settings" in the view) = "Input on pane config"

**Your mini panels**

- Context -> Required context: taxonomy terms
- Content -> (Your views) -> Settings -> "Term id" (probably named differently) = %taxonomy_term:tid

**Your main panel**

- Context: Add taxo term id. You will have to add each term id you will want to use as a context here.
- Content -> (Your mini panels) -> Settings, select the term you would like to use on that instance of the mini panel:

[image]